# JavaScript hide DIV tag if text is 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, trim

I have a problem. I'm trying to hide div if text is 0. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        if ($(".notification-counter").text() == "0") {
            $(".notification-counter").hide();
            $(".notification-container").hide();
        }
    });
</script>

<div class="dropdown nav-search pull-right <?php $this->_c('login') ?>">
    <a href="../pm/" class="dropdown-toggle"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i>
        <div class="notification-container">
            <div class="notification-counter">
                <?php
                      jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
                      $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_uddeim_simple_notifier');
                      echo JModuleHelper::renderModule( $module, $attribs );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>                                  
    </a>    
</div>
```

but it's not working... anyone can help? thanks for answers!

Comment: Try `if ($.trim($(".notification-counter").text()) === "0")`you have a space in DIV. Be aware, `.text()` will return the text of only first matched element, so if you have more than one `.notification-counter` element, you have to check it inside a loop and hide only respective container

Answer (score 4):

Try using `parseInt()` to make your comparison a number vs. a number rather than comparing text strings (it alleviates issues with whitespace. **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/783h57zy/)**

```
$(function () {
    if (parseInt($(".notification-counter").text()) == 0) {
        //$(".notification-counter").hide();
        $(".notification-container").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: as a side note, you don't need to hide the counter, you are already hidding the container. But that's said, this is more readable solution than trimming text imho.

Comment: @A.Wolff good point... i commented out the hide counter line.

Answer (score 3):

Use trim as there are white spaces

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v9nkuqz/)

```
$(function () {
    if ($.trim($(".notification-counter").text()) == "0") {
        $(".notification-counter").hide();
        $(".notification-container").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why downvotes ? I gave correct answer with fiddle !!

Comment: Looks like there's someone that's downvoting everything.. :/

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the quotes around 0, and it would work fine.

```
$(function () {
    if ($(".notification-counter").text() == 0) {
        $(".notification-counter").hide();
        $(".notification-container").hide();
    }
});
```

Additional Information:
Since many here seem to be unclear, here's a little helper:
Try this in your console

```
 //hit F12 to view the console
var counter = $(".notification-counter");
var container = $(".notification-container");
console.log(container.text(), container.html());
console.log(container.text() == 0,container.text() == "0");
//true, false
console.log(typeof 0, typeof "0");
//number, string
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhwga9m7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var notificationCounter = $('.notification-counter');
if (notificationCounter.text().trim() === '0') {
  notificationCounter.closest('.notification-container').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: instead of .text() put .html()

```
$(function() {
  if ($(".notification-counter").html() == "0") {
    $(".notification-counter").hide();
    $(".notification-container").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Where possible, it's better to put a bit of explanation of what your code does, as well as linking to relevant documentation -- this will help to gain reputation and privileges! For more tips, take a look at [answer]. Thanks!